# Kotlin CountDownTimer lateinit property has not been initialized and CoreComponentFactory not found

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create a pomodoro timer app.  It was working previously, but after changing some things, it breaking and then trying to recreate the working code. I can't figure out what is wrong.

In `Logcat` I am getting both

> Didn't find "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory

a while after failing and closing, and

> 'kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property timer
>   has not been initialized'

directly after failing.  I've tried changing the `gradle` file as suggested in other late-init code problems but that doesn't seem to be what it is.

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.carrottimer

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Switch
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.bignerdranch.android.carrottimer.util.PrefUtil

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_timer.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_timer.*
import java.util.*

class TimerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

enum class TimerState{
    Stopped, Paused, Running
}

private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer
private var timerLengthSeconds: Long = 0
private var timerState = TimerState.Stopped

var secondsRemaining: Long = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer)
    supportActionBar?.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer)
    supportActionBar?.title = "    Carrot Timer"

    val sw = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch1)
    sw?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        val msg = if (isChecked) "ON" else "OFF"
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        sw.text = msg
    }

    but_pomodoro.setOnClickListener{v ->
        timer.cancel()
        PrefUtil.setTimerLength(25)
        onTimerFinished()
    }

    but_short.setOnClickListener{v ->
        timer.cancel()
        PrefUtil.setTimerLength(5)
        onTimerFinished()
    }

    but_long.setOnClickListener{v ->
        timer.cancel()
        PrefUtil.setTimerLength(10)
        onTimerFinished()
    }

    fab_start.setOnClickListener{v ->
        startTimer()
        timerState =  TimerState.Running
        updateButtons()
    }

    fab_pause.setOnClickListener { v ->
        timer.cancel()
        timerState = TimerState.Paused
        updateButtons()
    }

    fab_stop.setOnClickListener { v ->
        timer.cancel()
        onTimerFinished()
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    initTimer()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

    if (timerState == TimerState.Running){
        timer.cancel()
    }

    PrefUtil.setPreviousTimerLengthSeconds(timerLengthSeconds, this)
    PrefUtil.setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining, this)
    PrefUtil.setTimerState(timerState, this)
}

private fun initTimer(){
    timerState = PrefUtil.getTimerState(this)

    if (timerState == TimerState.Stopped)
        setNewTimerLength()
    else
        setPreviousTimerLength()

    secondsRemaining = if (timerState == TimerState.Running || timerState == TimerState.Paused)
        PrefUtil.getSecondsRemaining(this)
    else
        timerLengthSeconds

    if (timerState == TimerState.Running)
        startTimer()

    updateButtons()
    updateCountdownUI()
}

private fun onTimerFinished(){
    timerState = TimerState.Stopped

    setNewTimerLength()

    PrefUtil.setSecondsRemaining(timerLengthSeconds, this)
    secondsRemaining = timerLengthSeconds

    updateButtons()
    updateCountdownUI()
}

private fun startTimer(){
    timerState = TimerState.Running

    timer = object : CountDownTimer(secondsRemaining * 1000, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() = onTimerFinished()

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            secondsRemaining = millisUntilFinished / 1000
            updateCountdownUI()
        }
    }.start()
}

private fun setNewTimerLength(){
    val lengthInMinutes = PrefUtil.getTimerLength(this)
    timerLengthSeconds = (lengthInMinutes * 60L)
}

private fun setPreviousTimerLength(){
    timerLengthSeconds = PrefUtil.getPreviousTimerLengthSeconds(this)
}

private fun updateCountdownUI(){
    val minutesUntilFinished = secondsRemaining / 60
    val secondsInMinuteUntilFinished = secondsRemaining - minutesUntilFinished * 60
    val secondsStr = secondsInMinuteUntilFinished.toString()
    textView_countdown.text = "$minutesUntilFinished:${if (secondsStr.length == 2) secondsStr else "0" + secondsStr}"
}

private fun updateButtons(){
    when (timerState) {
        TimerState.Running ->{
            fab_start.isEnabled = false
            fab_pause.isEnabled = true
            fab_stop.isEnabled = true
        }
        TimerState.Stopped -> {
            fab_start.isEnabled = true
            fab_pause.isEnabled = false
            fab_stop.isEnabled = false
        }
        TimerState.Paused -> {
            fab_start.isEnabled = true
            fab_pause.isEnabled = false
            fab_stop.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_timer, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Initialize the timer somewhere, maybe in onCreate, it’s lateinit so you use it in fabs clicks, for ex. timer.cancel() but it’s only decalred, not initialized like timer = new CountDownTimer(); even if it is later initialized on start click there is some use where it’s null

Answer (score 2):

Why you must define timer as `lateinit` field, change this LOC to

```
private var timer: CountDownTimer? = null
```

So now you can handle timer clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out that it was because I am telling it to cancel, even if it isn't running. To solve it I just added an if statement in case it it wasn't running:

```
    but_pomodoro.setOnClickListener{v ->
        if (timerState == TimerState.Running) {
            timer.cancel()
        }
        PrefUtil.setTimerLength(25)
        onTimerFinished()
    }
```

Thank you for the help, it pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made the timer property nullable and initialized it in the init block of the view model.

```
private var timer:CountDownTimer?

init{
timer=NULL
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error because my timer was **lateinit**, and in some scenarios, it wasn't initialized.
To avoid this issue, I checked the condition before using the timer. For example, I checked if it was initialized before canceling it:

```
        if (this::timer.isInitialized){
            timer.cancel()
        }
```